wandb.log matplotlib pcolormesh
I'm trying to generate a pcolormesh object. And then using wandb.log to log it, but I saw that wandb by default will convert this figure to plotly first. And that's why I end up with this warning and nothing is shown for my plot:
Dang! That path collection is out of this world. I totally don't know what to do with it yet! Plotly can only import path collections linked to 'data' coordinates
Here's what I'm doing in my code:

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.pcolormesh(out_abs.cpu())
    plt.ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    plt.xlabel('Time')

    return fig

It seems the solution would be either make this fig with plotly from the start or convert it to plotly.
Thanks!

A workaround right now I have is to convert the matplotlib figure into image object in wandb by wandb.Image(fig)
